# Excel VBA to merge and append PDFs runs with no error but does not complete task

Tags: vba, excel

I have managed to compile the following VBA code, with a great deal of help from all you helpful folks out there.  It now runs without error but for some reason the merge section only merges the first 3 rows of my 6 rows of data (There will be more data so I need to make sure it's merging everything as it won't be so easy to see in future). The last loop of the sub doesn't seem to do anything, no files are appended...  Does anyone have any idea what I've done wrong? I'm lost!

```
Sub GenerateTAs()

Dim WeekFolder As String, YearFolder As String, ContentWeekFolder As String, Wc As String
Dim wdOutputName, wdInputName, PDFFileName As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim nRows As Integer
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim i As Integer    
Dim InpUrl As String
Dim OutFilePath As String
Dim DownloadStatus As Long
Dim gPDDoc1 As AcroPDDoc
Dim gPDDoc2 As AcroPDDoc

YearFolder = "R:\TAs\" & Sheets("TAs").Range("Q1").Value
Wc = Format(Sheets("TAs").Range("Q3").Value, "dd.mm.yyyy")
WeekFolder = YearFolder & "\" & Wc
ContentWeekFolder = YearFolder & "\TA Content\" & Wc

If Dir(WeekFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    Shell ("cmd /c mkdir """ & WeekFolder & """")
End If
If Dir(ContentWeekFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    Shell ("cmd /c mkdir """ & ContentWeekFolder & """")
End If

wdInputName = "R:\TAs\TA Cover Sheet.docx"
Const wdFormLetters = 0, wdOpenFormatAuto = 0
Const wdSendToNewDocument = 0, wdDefaultFirstRecord = 1, wdDefaultLastRecord = 3

'This will get you the number of records "-1" accounts for header
With Worksheets("CoverSheetGen")
    nRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
End With

' open the mail merge layout file
Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdInputName, "Word.document")
wdDoc.Application.Visible = False

For x = 1 To nRows

    With wdDoc.MailMerge
         .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
         .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
         .SuppressBlankLines = True
          With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
        End With
         .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
    With Worksheets("CoverSheetGen")
        PDFFileName = WeekFolder & "\" & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(x + 1, 10) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(x + 1, 9) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(x + 1, 15) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(x + 1, 6) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(x + 1, 8) & ".pdf"
    End With
    With wdDoc.MailMerge.DataSource
         .ActiveRecord = x
         If .ActiveRecord > .LastRecord Then Exit For
    End With
    ' show and save output file
    'cells(x+1,2)references the first cells starting in row 2 and increasing by 1 row with each loop
    wdDoc.Application.Visible = False
    wdDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat PDFFileName, 17   ' This line saves a .pdf-version of the mail merge
Next x

' cleanup
wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=FalseSet wdDoc = Nothing

With Worksheets("CoverSheetGen")
    cRows = .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
For i = 1 To cRows
    If Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> "" Then
    'Read Input Path for the File and Output File Destination Path
    InpUrl = Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
    OutFilePath = ContentWeekFolder & "\" & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(i + 1, 10) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(i + 1, 15) & ".pdf"

    'Invoke API to download file from the website.
    DownloadStatus = URLDownloadToFile(0, InpUrl, OutFilePath, 0, 0)

    End If
Next i

For A = 1 To aRows
    Set gPDDoc1 = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    Set gPDDoc2 = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

    If Dir(ContentWeekFolder & "\" & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(A + 1, 10) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(A + 1, 15) & ".pdf") <> "" Then

        chk1 = gPDDoc1.Open(WeekFolder & "\" & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(A + 1, 10) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(A + 1, 9) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(A + 1, 15) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(A + 1, 6) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(A + 1, 8) & ".pdf")
        chk2 = gPDDoc2.Open(ContentWeekFolder & "\" & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(A + 1, 10) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(A + 1, 15) & ".pdf")
        mergefile = gPDDoc1.InsertPages(0, gPDDoc2, 0, 1, 0)
        savemergefile = gPDDoc1.Save(1, WeekFolder & "\" & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(A + 1, 10) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(A + 1, 9) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(A + 1, 15) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(A + 1, 6) & " - " & Sheets("CoverSheetGen").Cells(A + 1, 8) & ".pdf")

    End If
Next A

End Sub

Function FileExist(path As String) As Boolean
    If Dir(path) <> vbNullString Then FileExist = True
End Function
Function IsFolderExists(txt As String) As Boolean
    IsFolderExists = _
        CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FolderExists(txt)
End Function
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the `For A = 1 to aRows` loop?  If so, what debugging have you done? The first thing I see in there is an `If Dir(...` -- are you sure that function returns `True` for every value of `A`?

Comment: Yes I do mean the For A=1 to a Rows loop. I have tried running the code without the IF function but it makes no difference therefore I conclude that the If is not the problem... Good idea though.

Comment: You need to do more than just *run* the code. Step through it line-by-line in debug mode. You will probably have a much easier time *seeing* where it's going wrong, than anyone here who has to basically just *guess* since you probably can't provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (because this requires a host of other files/network structure, etc.).

Comment: Otherwise, it is not immediately apparent to me, even after completely reformatting your code for readability, where in this code the "six lines" of data are to be identified. So the other thing you want to do is check and see if it's actually identifying 6 lines -- IOW, at this point, even you are simply *guessing* at what the problem is and where it may (or may not be) occurring. If you can do some more investigation, you can most likely solve it on your own, or you can at least help narrow down the possible issues :)